# Is there any command line in Mercurial to show the repository tree

Tags: command-line, mercurial

I want to view the tree of the repository.
Is there any command line in mercurial can do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Both workable.

```
hg glog
hg view
```

Comment: @akluth 's tip is very useful. Don´t forget to activate the extension `graphlog` to use `hg glog` command.

Comment: With glog you will likely want to use -l to specify the max number of commits to see

Answer (score 16):

You can try this too:

```
$ hg serve
```

Comment: Nice solution. :)

Comment: I like the fact that no extensions are needed for this one to work!

Answer (score 14):

Be sure to activate the needed extensions in your .hgrc file, otherwise `hg view` and `hg glog` will fail:

```
...

[extensions]
hgk =
graphlog =
...
```

Make sure that there is a blank line before `[extensions]`.

Comment: under Windows : `notepad %USERPROFILE%\.hgrc`  .This file may not exists on a new installation. for linux simply `vi ~/.hgrc`

Comment: Thanks! this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is currently deprecated. This feature has been included in core Mercurial:

```
hg log --graph
```